# Serverless: Usage of layers from other AWS accounts, how to do it?

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

I'm trying to deploy and use a Serverless function that uses a layer that was create by AWS which includes [NumPy and SciPy](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-for-aws-lambda-use-any-programming-language-and-share-common-components/)

relevant section of my Servelerless.yml file:

```
functions:
  pricing:
    handler: handler.pricing
    layers:
      - arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:399891621064:layer:AWSLambda-Python36-SciPy1x:2
```

when I run *sls deploy* then check the Lambda console, I can see the layer is there alongside my function, but when I try to call my lambda I get the error:

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'handler': No module named 'numpy'
```

relevant line of my handler.py file:

```
import numpy as np
```

*Edit:*
Even more strange, in the Lambda console, if I remove my (what appears to be the exact same) reference to the AWS published layer, and choose the 'Add a layer' button and select the exact same layer (same ARN), everything works.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I have managed to get it working, I think the issue was a mismatch in python versions, the arn based scipy library I was referencing with 3.6, and in my serverless.yml file I was referencing 3.7.

Next step is to figure out how to get

> serverless invoke local -f myfunction --docker

in my virtual env to actually work so that I can run and test this locally.